# I am not able to save user address,browser or time it always say syntax error

Tags: php

Hey friends today I am trying to save user id,date or browser but it is not working...... everytime when I upload my script to my hosting site say syntax error

```
<?php
$file = fopen(‘log.html’, ‘a’);
fwrite( $file, ‘<b>Ip Address:</b> $REMOTE_ADDR<br/>’);
fwrite( $file, ‘<b>Browser:</b> $HTTP_USER_AGENT<hr/>’);
fclose( $file );
?>
```

Comment: What plz explain clearly

Comment: you use strange quotes char `’` please use `'` instead

Comment: You HAVE syntax errors.. do not use `‘` characters.. use `'`

Comment: Don't edit your code in Word (or whatever), use a programmer's text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of single quotes. Try this instead:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('log.html', 'a');
fwrite( $file, '<b>Ip Address:</b> $REMOTE_ADDR<br/>');
fwrite( $file, '<b>Browser:</b> $HTTP_USER_AGENT<hr/>');
fclose( $file );
?>
```

Comment: cmon u could comment it man :D

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili It is the correct answer **and** it is copyable so he gets it right ;-)

Comment: Sure anyone would appreciate ur work, but I mean something else :p

Comment: Thanks a loot @klaus

Answer (score 1):

[PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) may be quoted with U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK (`"`) or U+0027 : APOSTROPHE (`'`), you are using U+2018 : LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, which is not allowed (HEREDOC and NOWDOC are also valid options, but not ones which make sense in this context).